# How to set one counter for two forloops?

Tags: django, django-templates, django-template-filters

I have table:

```
{% for item in items %}
    <tr>
        <td>{{ forloop.counter }}</td>
        <td>{{ item.field }}</td>
    </tr>
    {% for child in item.childs.all %}
        <tr>
            <td>{{ forloop.counter }}</td>
            <td>{{ child.field }}</td>
        </tr>
    {% endfor %}
{% endfor %}
```

But the second forloop.counter counts inside the second loop from 1. I want to get only one counter for all rows. How to do it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could [write a custom template tag](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/howto/custom-template-tags/#simple-tags) to calculate the counter (assuming that each row has an equal number of columns):

```
@register.simple_tag
def abs_counter(row, col, col_total)
    return return ((row - 1) * col_total) + col
```

and

```
{% for item in items %}
...
    {% for child in items.children.all %}
        {% abs_counter forloop.parentloop.counter forloop.counter items.children.all|length %}
    {% endfor %}
{% endfor %}
```